# Show multiple Y axis stacked one upon the Other in Highchart Line type graph

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have Highchart 4.2.4 Line type Chart drawing the Graph with multiple Series data. The data can be categorised in two types for e.g. Type A and Type B. What I need to do is show Y Axis of series belonging to category A on Left and category B to right. As shown in image. **I need to know if I can show category B series Y axis stacked one upon the other. Even if the have same Y axis points for e.g. both have 0 and 1 as Y axis value. But it should be showing series data and its Y axis one upon the other like stack(newest series on the top)**

[image: Image showing Y axis on right(Red and Orange series and Y axis) stacked one upon the other with same Y axis data i.e. 0,1]

Is this Possible to achieve in highchart/ any similar example that meets my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

In the Highcharts you can declare multiple yAxis like in the demo:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

For this specific demo, you should use the Renderer to add the paths and labels.

Docs:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text